# Given $A$ , $m \times n$, $b \in R^m$, $x'$ is a solution to $A^TAx' = A^Tb$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ , $m \times n$ with real coefficients, $b \in R^m$, $x'$ is a solution to $A^TAx' = A^Tb$.

Prove that vector $(Ax' - b)$ is orthogonal to $(Ax - Ax')$ for every $x \in R^n$.

Well, I know that $Ax' = p$ is the orthogonal vector. But I struggle with defining what is $Ax$.

How can I show that $(p - b)\cdot(Ax - p) = 0$ , is there a trick with adding and distracting  a vector in the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left\langle Ax'-b,Ax-Ax'\right\rangle&=\left\langle Ax'-b,A(x-x')\right\rangle=\left\langle A^T(Ax'-b),x-x'\right\rangle
\\&=\left\langle A^TAx'-A^Tb,x-x'\right\rangle=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: I didn't understand the last equality, can you explain please?

Comment: It follows from the starting equation

Comment: But how did you get from the second quality to the third equality, how did A vanish in $A(x - x')$ and how $A^T$ appeared in $A^T(Ax' - b)$?

Comment: The transpose have the property $(x,Ay)=(A^Tx,y)$

Comment: Never heard of that.

Comment: That is because $\langle x,Ay\rangle=x^\top (Ay)=\left(A^\top x\right)^\top y=\left\langle A^\top x,y\right\rangle$.

Comment: @Batominovski Perfect! thank you!